# Concatenating array [a,c,e] and [b,d,f] so that it equals [ab,cd,ef] - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

Is there a way that I can do a some sort of concatenation of an array with the values `[a,c,e]` and another array with values `[b,d,f]` so that I can get an array with the values `[ab, cd, ef]`, using JavaScript. Or at least make those two arrays into [`a,b,c,d,e,f]`

I'm rather new to JavaScript and I have tried searching for this already, but I don't quite know how to phrase the question to find what I'm looking for. If anyone can point me towards an existing question about this, then it'd be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by `ab`, etc. in the `[ab, cd, ef]` array. Do you mean that `a` and `b` are always strings and `ab` should be `a+b` (i.e. string concatenation of `a` and `b`)?

Comment: var concated = a1.map(function(val, index){ return val + a2[index]; });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, assuming those letters are strings

```
var arr1 = ['a','c','e'],
    arr2 = ['b','d','f'];


var arr3 = arr1.map(function(item,i) {
    return item + arr2[i];
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E8z8R/)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `.zip()` but that's kind-of what this is; a `.zip()` followed by a `.map()` to join the results.

Comment: @Pointy - it is indeed a zip. One could also concat the array, or just join the strings and split again or any number of choices, but that's because the OP's example is one letter for each index, it think a zip and map is what the OP is really asking for, keeping the index etc ?

Answer (score 1):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9rhP/)

To get the alternative output you requested, where all the letters are still individual tokens but in a sorted array, you can do this:

```
var a1 = ['a','c','e'];
var a2 = ['b','d','f'];


var a3 = a1.concat(a2).sort();
```

> Resulting array a3 is ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]